# Concise arrow function body grammar

Tags: javascript, specifications, arrow-functions

As I understand it, there are two kinds of arrow function body: concise and verbose.

```
()=>1 // Concise
()=>{} // Not concise?
```

Concise lacks braces and is an [`AssignmentExpression`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-AssignmentExpression), and verbose is presumably a block, but I am not sure.

[14.2 of the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) defines the grammar of arrow functions, but it appears to include braces in the definition of the concise body.

```
1.  ConciseBody[In]:
2.      [lookahead ≠ {]ExpressionBody[?In, ~Await]
3.      {FunctionBody[~Yield, ~Await]}
```

Where am I going wrong? Where is the "verbose" body grammar defined in the spec?

Comment: It's a block of code just like the body of a `function` function.

Comment: See how in the spec it says "lookahead ≠ {"?

Comment: Deleted my comments because I had misread the grammar in pretty much the same way you did :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's specifying two options under ConciseBody: either an ExpressionBody (no brackets) **OR** a FunctionBody wrapped in brackets.

The format for how the spec is written is explained under "Grammar Notation", https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grammar-notation

Comment: Right. The non-terminal *ConciseBody* covers all `=>` function bodies, either a single expression with an implicit `return`, or a full-on traditional *FunctionBody*.

Comment: So the body of an arrow function is always a `ConciseBody`?

Comment: @Ben yes that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

According to the spec terminology, every `ArrowFunction` has a `ConsiseBody`, and then those are distinguished in short `ExpressionBody` ones and normal brace-wrapped `FunctionBody` ones.

The commonly used terminology in the JS world (like [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)) does however often distinguish  between a "concise body" and a "block body", which makes more sense to me personally.

Comment: Seems like it stemmed from a misreading of the spec (or something). It surely should be expression body vs block body?

Comment: @Ben The `ExpressionBody` nonterminal is new, formerly (ES6 - when the feature was introduced, discussed everywhere, and terminology coined) the `ConciseBody` was built directly from an `AssignmentExpression`. Maybe there was an earlier spec draft where it even did not contain the block body production. But yeah, could've been a misreading as well.

Comment: @Ben Apparently [it's quite new](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commit/a879fd542718bcab6accd2d38964c410fffa28a9), introduced with ES2019.

Comment: True but even before that changeset, 'ConciseBody` encapsulated both kinds of body (previously `AssignmentExpression` and `FunctionBody`).